# How to use awesome WM with LXSession (LXDE, Lubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awesome-wm

I have `Lubuntu`. But when i tried to use clean `Awesome WM`, i thought that can i use awesome WM with `GTK` themes. I this possible?

I tried to run `awesome`, but got:

```
E: awesome: main:463: another window manager is already running
```

Also, clean `Awesome WM` works fine without Lubuntu. How to use `awesome WM` as a Window Manager in Lubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some case, you can add `--replace` to replace the current window manager. LXDE defaults to OpenBox.

Some desktop environment also have settings to replace the window manager (in this case, by AwesomeWM). A quick googling seems to indicate some distribution store this setting in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/default`.

However this is a bit of going in circle around the real issue here. Why run AwesomeWM in LXDE? Their feature set overlap at a rate of almost 100%. If you use lxde only for lxappearance (gtk theme mananger) and PCManFM, note that those 2 applications run just fine from the normal Awesome session. AwesomeWM itself provide the panel, wallpaper and window manager features, which leaves nothing from the original LXDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are really got right! In my case, i have not `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/default`, insead of this i have `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf`.  But what realy helps me - its `lxsession-default-apps`